# Porque mi programa me devuelve "basura"?

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa que a través de la siguiente clase pueda cargar los datos y mostrarlos que hasta este momento funciona.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;


class Obra{

private:
    int codigoObra;
    int codigoProvincia;
    char codigoEmpresaConstructora[5];
    int dia,mes,anio;
    float cantMetrosCuadrados;
    float inversion;

public:

    int getCodigoObra(){return codigoObra;}
    int getCodigoProvincia(){return codigoProvincia;}
    const char *getCodigoEmpresaConstructora(){return codigoEmpresaConstructora;}
    int getDia(){return dia;}
    int getMes(){return mes;}
    int getAnio(){return anio;}
    float getCantMetrosCuadrados(){return cantMetrosCuadrados;}
    float getInversion(){return inversion;}


    void cargar();
    void mostrar();

    bool grabarEnDisco(){

        FILE *p;



        p=fopen("obras.dat", "ab");

        if(p == NULL){

            cout<<"ERROR DE ARCHIVO"<<endl;
            return false;
        }

        bool escribio = fwrite(this,sizeof(Obra),1,p);

        fclose(p);
        return escribio;


    }

    bool leerDeDisco(int pos){

        FILE *p;

        p = fopen("obras.dat", "rb");

        ///wb abre el archivo en modo escritura -> SIEMPRE CREA UN ARCHIVO VACIO
        ///ab abre el archivo y permite que se le agreguen registros.
        ///rb abre el archivo y permite leer los registros. Si no existe da error.

        if(p == NULL){
            cout<<"ERROR DE ARCHIVO";
            return false;
        }

        fseek(p,sizeof(Obra)*pos,0);

        bool leyo = fread(this,sizeof(Obra),1,p);
        fclose(p);
        return leyo;
    }


};
```

El problema que tengo es lo siguiente. Estoy tratando de buscar el año que tenga el menor monto de inversion. Para ello intente realizar una funcion que lea los registros del archivo y que si el anio que le paso a la funcion es el mismo que obtengo de getAnio entonces acumule la inversion en una variable, y luego compare esa variable con una que contiene el valor minimo. Si mi variable que contiene la acumulacion de las inversiones es menor a la variable que contiene el minimo, entonces esa suma de inversiones pasaría a ser el nuevo minimo y por ende el getAnio seria el anio con menor inversion. Pero por alguna razon cuando lo muestro me devuelve basura.

```
float calcularInversion(){

    Obra obj;

    int pos = 0, anio;

    float minInversion = 9999999, sumaInversion=0;
    int minAnio;




    while(obj.leerDeDisco(pos++)){

        if(obj.getAnio()==anio){

            sumaInversion+=obj.getInversion();

            if(sumaInversion<minInversion){
                minAnio = obj.getAnio();
            }

        }

    }

    cout<<"El anio con menos inversion fue: "<<minAnio<<endl;
    return minAnio;

}
```

Comment: Esta funcion: calcularInversion tiene un monton de cosas sin definir o me parece a mi?

Comment: Que es lo que tiene sin definir? @gbianchi

Comment: Esto por ejemplo, int minAnio; no toma cualquier valor?

Comment: minAnio está sin inicializar

Answer (score 0):

La única manera de que "*te devuelva basura*" sería usando una variable sin inicializar. En tu caso la variable sin inicializar sería la que estás mostrando por pantalla:

```
cout<<"El anio con menos inversion fue: "<<minAnio<<endl;
//       Posiblemente sin inicializar ---> ~~~~~~~
```

¿Cabe la posibilidad de que `minAnio` no cambie su estado de *sin inicializar* a *con valor* durante la ejecución? Aparentemente si:

```
if(obj.getAnio()==anio){ // Primera condición: 'anio' está sin inicializar.

    sumaInversion+=obj.getInversion();

    if(sumaInversion<minInversion) { // Segunda condición.
        minAnio = obj.getAnio();
    }
}
```

Si la primera y/o la segunda condición no se cumplen nunca, `minAnio` no recibiría un valor, por lo que se quedaría con su valor inicial que, al ser no inicializado será "*basura*".

Yo sospecho de la primera condición, ya que al no estar inicializada la variable `anio` su valor será también "*basura*" y dicho valor será muy probablemente diferente a cualquier año que tengas almacenado.